# Removing an element that is same from both lists in python

Tags: python

I am writing a function to delete an element which is the same in both lists.

```
 def del_same_elements(num1,num2):
        for i in range(0,len(num1)):
            for j in range(0,len(num2)):

                if num1[i] == num2[j]:
                    same = num1[i]

        num1.remove(same)
        num2.remove(same)

        return num1,num2
```

Calling `print (del_same_elements([3,11],[2,2,3]))` returns `[11],[2,2]` as expected, but when trying `print (del_same_elements([3],[2,2]))` I get the error `local variable 'same' referenced before assignment`. How do I handle the case where there are no same values?

Comment: `Calling print (del_same_elements([3,11],[2,2])) returns [11],[2,2] as expected`

How it is possible? There is no common elements in both lists?

Comment: I made a typo! I will edit.

Comment: If you have lists `[2]` and `[2,2]`, do you expect to get two empty lists out, or should the second one still have one `2`? Also, is it desirable (or especially undesirable) for the list modifications to happen in place?

Comment: I would expect [] and [2].

Comment: Please describe in detail and with more samples what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Using set `intersection` to detect the common elements:

```
def rm_same(num1, num2):
    same = set(num1).intersection(num2)
    for s in same:
        num1.remove(s)
        num2.remove(s)
    return num1, num2
```

Comment: you don't really need the `if` since looping in an empty list will simply not execute the block.

Comment: you don't need to convert the set to a list either :)

Comment: Edited to avoid non necessary operation :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a bit of set theory and calculate the intersection of the list and then remove the items intersection

```
def del_same_elements(num1, num2):
    same = list(set(num1) & set(num2))

    for i in same:
        num1.remove(i)
        num2.remove(i)

    return num1, num2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num1, num2 = del_same_elements([1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,5,6])

print num1
print num2
```

the result

```
[2, 4]
[6]
```

This also worked perfectly where there is not interseciton since nothing will be removed

Comment: This is perfect! I never even thought of this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could have written program like this

```
def del_same_elements(num1,num2):
    for num in num1 + num2:
        if num in num1 and num in num2:
            num1.remove(num)
            num2.remove(num)

    return num1, num2

print (del_same_elements([3,11],[2,2, 3]))
```

This can be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

OR, you could use sets instead:

```
same = set(num1) & set(num2)

while same:
    val = same.pop()
    num1.remove(val)
    num2.remove(val)
```

Which at least avoids those nested loops.

Comment: Apologies for being slow in producing a set solution!